# Equivalence of variable selection criteria in forward stepwise regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, stepwise-regression

Say we have already selected $x_1$ through $x_k$.

To select the next variable, forward stepwise regression either:

a. picks the variable that when added to the already selected variables, gives the highest $R^2$ when regressed with $y$

or

b. picks the variable that has the highest correlation with the residuals of the regression of $y$ on the already selected variables.

Why are these two criteria equivalent?

Comment: I think (b) cannot possibly be correct, because the covariance depends on the units of measurement of the explanatory variables, which would make this criterion arbitrary.  Don't you mean *correlation* instead of *covariance*?

Comment: @whuber you're right I've updated the question

Comment: Thank you (+1).  I suspect you can find the answer among [our posts on the relationship between $R^2$ and correlation coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=R%5E2+correlation).